# Why does Array.prototype.forEach() not recognize await within an async function the same as a for loop?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, async-await

Using `await` in a `for` loop within an `async` function provides the expected result of the execution awaiting the completion of the current `Promise` within the iteration

```js
const story = [1,2,3,4,5];

(async() => {

  for (var i = 0; i < story.length; i++) {
    await new Promise(function(resolve) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        resolve(story[i])
      }, 1000)
    }).then(function(chapter) {
      document.body
        .appendChild(document.createTextNode(chapter));
    });
  }

})()
```

Why does `Array.prototype.forEach()` not provide the same functionality of awaiting the fulfillment of the current `Promise` when `await` is using within the callback passed to `.forEach()`?

```js
const story = [1,2,3,4,5];

(async() => {

  story.forEach(async function(chapterUrl) {
    // does not await for Promise fulfillment
    await new Promise(function(resolve) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        resolve(chapterUrl)
      }, 1000)
    }).then(function(chapter) {
      document.body
      .appendChild(document.createTextNode(chapter));
    });
  });
  
})();
```

Comment: @KevinB Unfortunately none of the answers explain _why_

Comment: The comments however do. Feel free to add a better answer there if you have one

Comment: @KevinB No, they do not. Unless you can link to the specific comments. If were to state the same thing would summarily be advised to put answers in answers instead of comments.

Comment: The answer itself does get into why forEach doesn't work. *"If you want to read the files in parallel, you cannot use forEach indeed. Each of the the async callback function calls does return a promise, **but you're throwing them away instead of awaiting them**."* of course, because forEach doesn't do anything with what the functions passed to it returns. it just doesn't quite spell it out as much as you might want it to.

Comment: It then continues with a .map solution that *does* work, for that very reason.

Comment: @KevinB You are referring to a comment, correct? And not a formal answer to the present Question? You cannot massage an answer to the present Question from comments following answers which did not answer the present question

Comment: No, i'm referring to the accepted answer.

Comment: The accepted answer does not explain _why_ there is different effect using `.forEach()` as to `for..in`, `for..of` or `for`. `for` loops do not `return` anything either

Comment: Yes it does. It explains that forEach cannot handle async callbacks properly because it throws away the returned promise. Directly in the quote i provided above.

Comment: @KevinB No, it does not, at least not for the present question to have an acceptable answer. "throwing them away"  is not an adequate answer. We would first need to clearly define what "throwing them away" or  "throws away" technically means relevant to a specification.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`await` suspends the current function until the `Promise` is resolved. When using multiple `await` calls in a `for` loop, they are all executed within the same block scope and, thus, wait for the previous one to finish before continuing.

When using the `forEach` function, each iteration of the loop is run in its own scope, so each `await` has no effect on the others.

Comment: By _"within the same function"_ do you mean within the same block scope?

Comment: Yes, edited to clarify